# Script execution doesn't stop when loop condition is false

Tags: javascript, setinterval, userscripts

Recently I wrote an userscript for auto betting on csgojustice. Here it is:

```
var delay = 10000
var btBet = document.getElementById("make-bet");
var loop = true
var input=document.createElement("input");
input.type="button";
input.value="Start";
input.onclick = start;
input.setAttribute("style", "font-size:18px;position:absolute;top:120px;right:40px;");
document.body.appendChild(input); 

var input=document.createElement("input");
input.type="button";
input.value="Stop";
input.onclick = stop;
input.setAttribute("style", "font-size:18px;position:absolute;top:120px;right:130px;");
document.body.appendChild(input); 

function start() {
    loop = true;
    roll(); 
}

function roll() {
    if (loop === true) {
        btBet.click();
        refreshIntervalId = setInterval(roll2, delay); }
}

function roll2() { 
    btBet.click();
    clearInterval(refreshIntervalId)'
    roll()
}

function stop() {
loop = false;
}
```

#### Problem:

When I click Start button, it starts executing. But when I click Stop button, it still executes. But there is `if (loop === true)` yet when `loop` is `false`, it doesn't stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't seem to experience your problem - this script works just fine for me.

But I have fixed a few things.

- The `roll2` function is not necessary.
- You can use `setTimeout` instead if `setInterval`, then you don't have to clear it every time
- you should `clearTimeout` when calling `stop`

#### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ocngLn3m/)

```
var delay = 1000;
var btBet = document.getElementById("make-bet");
var loop = true;
var input=document.createElement("input");
input.type="button";
input.value="Start";
input.onclick = start;
input.setAttribute("style", "font-size:18px;position:absolute;top:120px;right:40px;");
document.body.appendChild(input); 

var input=document.createElement("input");
input.type="button";
input.value="Stop";
input.onclick = stop;
input.setAttribute("style", "font-size:18px;position:absolute;top:120px;right:130px;");
document.body.appendChild(input); 

function start() {
    loop = true;
    roll(); 
}

function roll() {
    if (loop === true) {
        console.log("roll");
        refreshIntervalId = setTimeout(roll, delay);
    }
}

function stop() {
    loop = false;
    clearTimeout(refreshIntervalId);
}
```

Comment: I must add btBet.click(); after console.log and it starts, works and I can stop it! What was wrong in my script?

Comment: @Zireveen I have no idea, it worked for me just fine. The things I changed didn't fix anything, just improved the code.

Comment: Hmm... Strange. I copied the script that was ,,wrong'' and it didn't stop. Refreshed page, pasted Your version and everything works just fine! Thank You one more time!

Comment: The only real issue in your code is that you have `clearInterval(refreshIntervalId)'` instead of `clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);`. That causes parse error, but the script shouldn't execute at all in that case.

Comment: Hmm... I have dice script for csgohandouts with | ' | at the end and it works... Nah, I must learn coding more :D